# Create generic search API using spring and CouchBase

Tags: spring-boot, couchbase, spring-data-couchbase

I have a use case where I want to create a generic search API, the idea is to have a lot of filters in frontend part and the user will have the chance to use 0 or more filters, so say we have an object like

```
public class Person {
  public String name;
  public String age;
  // som other properties 
}
```

so in frontend part I want to send a `searchCriteria` for example

```
[{
   field: name,
   operator: eq,
   value: XX
}]
```

The problem is I can't find good way to map the `searchCriteria` to be used in the `crudRepository`.

so:

1. Is there a way I can do so without creating a service that construct the query and manually execute it?
2. Is there anything like `QueryDSL` that support `CouchBase` repositories?

I am using Spring boot and CouchBase

Thanks

Comment: I dont think couchbase is good idea for such kind of reqirement. Couchbase reply on the indexing a lot. You will have to create primary index which mean index on all the columns may dwongrade ur performance

Comment: unfortunately I have to use CouchBase for other reasons.

Answer (score 0):

spring-data-couchbase supports querydsl -

https://www.baeldung.com/rest-api-search-language-spring-data-querydsl

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)